# Get value with type from plist in swift

Tags: swift, plist

I have seen many examples of how to get a value from a plist in swift - however all involve type casting the variable after it is read from the plist. Since we already give the property a type when creating it in the plist, why do we have to type it again? Is there any way to read values from the plist with the type they have in the plist?

For example this is the approach I am using to read the value from a plist:

```
extension Bundle {
  var someVar: String {
    return object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "someVar") as? String ?? ""
  }
}
```

Why do I need to cast the variable again as String when I have already typed it as String in the plist?

Answer (score 1):

Because your plist is a `[String: Any]` dictionary. It can hold values that are not `String` and the compiler can't know what is what until you specifically tell it - via the casting you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Bruno - then why does the plist UI have you create the variables with a type in the first place?

Comment: @user2690354 The Swift programming language and Xcode are two different things. The plist UI you are seeing is an Xcode feature, not Swift's. Swift doesn't know anything about your Xcode project - you can even pass dictionary keys that don't exist to that function :)

Answer (score 1):

Please <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `object(forInfoDictionaryKey`. You will see

[image]

Since a property list can contain many different types (array, dictionary, string, url, numeric values, date, data) the return value is optional `Any` and you have to cast the type.

---

Apple provides another approach in `URL`: If you get a value from `resourceValues(forKeys` with an `URLResourceKey` you get also the expected type.

Feel free to write an extension of `Bundle` which considers also the actual type.